# how to Disable Next and Previous image buttons on Windows Photo and Fax Viewer?

Tags: c#, tiff

I wrote a simple code which opens multiple .tiff files but I want to disable next and previous buttons. Is it possible? Any ideas?

```
string Path = @"....\Desktop\Test Image.tif";

        Process p = new Process();

        p.StartInfo.FileName = "rundll32.exe";

        //Arguments
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"C:\WINDOWS\System32\shimgvw.dll,ImageView_Fullscreen " + Path;
        p.Start();
```

Comment: Did you find out how to handle the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using some Win32 API (FindWindow, SendMessage). You could get the hWnd of the buttons and use SendMessage on them.